# Balls into bins question. Where is the mistake?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins

I am not able to figure out a loophole in my argument related to popular "Balls into bins" problem.

Suppose there are $m$ balls and $n$ bins. The $m$ balls are thrown independently and uniformly at random into these $n$ bins. What is the probability that the first bin is empty ?

The answer to this question mentioned in : [Probability that first ball is empty](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2993053/579315)
is $\Big(1-\frac{1}{n}\Big)^m$ which seems fine.

This answer should match with the probability found using manual counting method.

My argument is:
The $m$ balls can be distributed into $n$ bins in ${m+n-1} \choose {n-1} $ ways. If first bin is empty, then $m$ balls can be distributed into remaining $(n-1)$ bins in ${m+n-2} \choose {n-2} $ ways. This implies,
$$P(\text{first bin is empty})=\frac{{m+n-2} \choose {n-2}}{ {m+n-1} \choose {n-1} }=\frac{n-1}{m+n-1}$$

The values of both probabilities are very close to each other but have different answers. What is wrong with my argument ?

Comment: You cannot extend star and bar method of counting combinations to probability. All individual combinations in star and bar method do not have equal probability.

Comment: The first solution assumes that the experiment is performed with replacement (i.e. you have infinite number of balls). You solution assumes that the experiment is without replacement (i.e. you have finite number of balls).

Comment: @MathLover I get it..Thanks

Comment: @rrv Thank you..I get it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a counting argument then each case must be equally likely.

Your ${m+n-1 \choose n-1}$ ways of distributing $m$ balls into $n$ bins are not equally likely.  There are $n^m$ equally likely ways of distributing the balls but some look similar to each other.

Take a simple example of $m=3,n=2$.  Then ${m+n-1 \choose n-1}= {4 \choose 1}=4$ wheile $n^m = 2^3=8$.  The different ways are:

- Three in the first bin, zero in the second bin $(AAA)$ with probability $\frac18$
- Two in the first bin, one in the second bin $(AAB, ABA, BAA)$  with probability $\frac38$
- One in the first bin, two in the second bin $(ABB, BAB, BBA)$   with probability $\frac38$
- Zero in the first bin, three in the second bin $(BBB)$ with probability $\frac18$

This last case is leaves the first bin empty and has probability $\frac18 = \left(1-\frac12\right)^3$.

Comment: Okay.. I get it. Thanks @Henry